# PowerMockito to test MongoClient Singleton

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have lazy singleton `MongoConnection` class with a static method which returns `MongoClient` instance on `MongoConnection.getClient()`:

```
 public class MongoConnection {

    private static MongoClient mongoclient;

    private MongoConnection() {

    }

    public static MongoClient getClient() {
        if (mongoclient == null) {
            // code to initialize MongoClient
        }
        return mongoclient;
    }
}
```

How do I use PowerMockito to mock `MongoConnection` singleton and test `getClient` method.

I don't have choice over singleton because there will be single instance of `MongoClient` across the application (as per MongoDB documentation).

Note: i don't want to connect to actual DB in test because it will be integration test rather than JUnit; I just want to make sure if `MongoClient` is initialized with expected parameters. How to do I achieve this with PockerMockito?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example shows you how to use Mockito with PowerMockito to mock your `MongoConnection.getMongoClient()`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MongoConnection.class})
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void aTestWhichRequiresMockingMongoConnection() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = Mockito.mock(MongoClient.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MongoConnection.class);

        Mockito.when(MongoConnection.getClient()).thenReturn(mongoClient);

        // set up some expectations on the mocked MongoClient returned by MongoConnection    
        Mockito.when(mongoClient.getDatabase("aDatabaseName")).thenReturn(...);

        // ... etc
    }
}
```

This class is verified for:

- Mockito v2.7.19
- PowerMock v1.7.0
- JUnit v4.12

As an aside, this:

> i don't have choice over singleton because there will be single instance of MongoClient across the application(as per MongoDB documentation).

... does not mandate you to make your `MongoClient` static. You could make `getClient()` a non static method and ensure that `MongoConnection` is a singleton i.e. that your application only has single instance of it. Dependency injection solutions (such as Spring, Guice) have built-in support for ensuring that a dependency can be configured as a singleton.